# DB2 online restore - “SQL1035N The database is currently in use.”

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I am trying to do `ONLINE RESTORE ROLLFORWARDING TO END OF LOGS AND COMPLETE`. When I run this command I am getting error SQL1035N The database is currently in use. It does not allow any connections to it!

If I deactivate database and then run command I can restore but then my database is not available for users but it should be becuase it is live production system 24/7. How to resolve this?

Comment: I may be mis-understanding your question (DB2 is not my strong side), but are you restoring to a separate table space than where the tables that the users should be able to access are stored?

Comment: Hi, no I am restoring in same table spaces that users are using

Comment: I am trying to do online restoration so users can use database!! I only have one database and one tablespace for data

Comment: Can I do this or I must disconnect all users and terminate all connections to database to be able to do RESTORE??? thanks

Comment: I'm not a DB2 guru, but reading the manual it looks that way; "ONLINE
This keyword, applicable only when performing a table space-level restore operation, is specified to allow a backup image to be restored online. This means that other agents can connect to the database while the backup image is being restored, and that the data in **other table spaces** will be available while the specified table spaces are being restored."

Comment: re-activate it when the restore is complete. However when you deactivate it, who ever was using it will get thrown off abrubtly. Restore requires exclusive access, so usually this is done when no one is using the db, or you politely close every one out. Or you have two copies of the db / file volume, and flip the system on to the restored one.

Comment: OK so conlusion is that no users can't be conneceted to the system during RESTORE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform an online restore, DB2 must lock the tablespace(s) you are trying to restore.  The restore process essentially overwrites the file on disk containing the tablespaces' data. This is incompatible with applications using data in the same tablespace while the restore occurs.

If your database has all data in a single tablespace, then an online restore is not particularly useful. If you have multiple tablespaces in the database, applications may be able to continue functioning while the corrupted tablespace(s) are restored, but of course this requires some planning in your application and database design.